# Implementing quicksort using median of three random elements of an array as pivot

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, median

I've been trying to implement this and for some reason the list is not getting sorted, it just gets randomly shuffled.

These are 3 different outputs when I execute the code 3 times:

1. `[2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 1]`
2. `[1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5]`
3. `[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

Using a fixed pivot such as `A[low]` works perfectly fine, when I try to implement the median of three random numbers it gets messy, I'm not sure why that is.
What am I missing / doing wrong?

```
def determine_median(a, b, c):
        if a > b:
            if a < c:
                median = a
            elif b > c:
                median = b
            else:
                median = c
        else:
            if a > c:
                median = a
            elif b < c:
                median = b
            else:
                median = c
        return median


def partition(A, low, high):
    l = len(A)

    # taking 3 random elements out of the array
    m1 = A[random.randint(0,l-1)]
    m2 = A[random.randint(0,l-1)]
    m3 = A[random.randint(0,l-1)]
    median = determine_median(m1, m2, m3)
    pivot = median
    i = low
    for j in range(low + 1, high + 1):
        if (A[j] < pivot):
            i = i + 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    A[i], A[low] = A[low], A[i]
    return i


def quicksort (A, low, high):
    if low < high:
        m = partition(A, low, high)
        quicksort (A, low, m-1)
        quicksort (A, m+1, high)
    return A

# testing
arr = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
n = len(arr)
print(quicksort(arr, 0, n-1))
```

**EDIT:**

My problem was that I was choosing from the entire list, not from the current subarray, as Jasonharper pointed out.

here is the fixed partition function:

```
def partition(A, low, high):
    m1 = A[random.randint(low,high)]
    m2 = A[random.randint(low,high)]
    m3 = A[random.randint(low,high)]
    median = determine_median(m1, m2, m3)
    pivotindex = A.index(median)
    A[low], A[pivotindex] = A[pivotindex], A[low]
    pivot = A[low]
    i = low
    for j in range(low + 1, high + 1):
        if (A[j] < pivot):
            i = i + 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    A[i], A[low] = A[low], A[i]
    return i
```

Comment: You are choosing your three possible pivots from *the entire list*, not just the partition of the list you're currently working on.

Comment: I think it would be a very good learning opportunity for you to investigate your own implementation carefully and find the bugs in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!
After realizing that I indeed was choosing from the entire list, I quickly found a way to  choose the random numbers from the subarray I'm currently working on.
Thanks again!